# Put camera in background in Cocos2d-3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I’d like to put, as a background of my game, the current view of the iphone’s built camera  and can’t find anything related to it here in `cocos2d-iphone-3.0`. I tried this http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/augmented-reality-tutorial-for-ios but it wont't helful.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[self.window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 depthFormat:0];

[CCDirector sharedDirector].view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[CCDirector sharedDirector].view.opaque = NO;

// set value for glClearColor
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

// prepare the overlay view and add it to the window
overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
overlay.opaque = NO;
overlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.window addSubview:overlay];

#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM  1.24299

UIImagePickerController *uip;

@try {
    uip = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
    uip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    uip.showsCameraControls = NO;
    uip.toolbarHidden = YES;
    uip.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    uip.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    uip.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(uip.cameraViewTransform,
                                                     CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    uip = nil;
}
@finally {
    if(uip) {
        [overlay addSubview:[uip view]];
    }
}
[CCDirector sharedDirector].view = glView;
 #ifdef APPORTABLE
if([cocos2dSetup[CCSetupScreenMode] isEqual:CCScreenModeFixed])
    [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode = [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenAspectFitEmulationMode];
else
   [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode = [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenScaledAspectFitEmulationMode];
#endif

// Configure CCFileUtils to work with SpriteBuilder
[CCBReader configureCCFileUtils];

// Do any extra configuration of Cocos2d here (the example line changes the pixel format for faster rendering, but with less colors)
//[cocos2dSetup setObject:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 forKey:CCConfigPixelFormat];

[self setupCocos2dWithOptions:cocos2dSetup];
[self createAdmobAds];

return YES;
 }
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: the procedure should be the same or very similar as in v2: make the view transparent (opaque=NO), change framebuffer to RGBA8888 (32-bit color depth), ensure image picker view is in the background by inserting it before the cocos2d view to the window (don't add it as child of the cocos2d view)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanx for reply i tried but it wont work . you can see my code.

Comment: "won't work" meaning what exactly? Crash? Error message? No picker just cocos view? Only picker no cocos view?

Comment: [window_ addSubview:overlay]; it will succesfulle add but after cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00 then application should be crash and no picker view.

Comment: i have added above code in this method  [self setupCocos2dWithOptions:cocos2dSetup];

Comment: It doesn't look like you added your glView to your CCDirector.  Also (for anyone else struggling with this) it's important to set the CCGLView's opaque = NO and glClearColor() after you add the CCGLView to the director. Doing these changes prior to adding the CCGLView to the CCDirector does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
-(void) setIsOverlayingDeviceCamera: (BOOL) aBool
```

in CCNodeController.